# ata* problem! also dvd rom is not detected

Tags: dvd, disk, sata

I have a problem with my Ubuntu 14.04. When I press Ctrl + Alt + F1, it always says:

```
login: [18.92] ata3: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4040000 action 0xe frozen
[18.93] ata3: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[21.13] ata3: SError { CommWake DevExch }
```

Also, it writes the 2nd and 3rd line till infinity every 2 secs. My ubuntu is not able to read the disks anymore. Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the ata controller on the motherboard. Is everything also running really slow?

It is worth booting on a live USB and seeing if the errors are still coming in. I had the same issue, I got the errors even with no HDDs plugged in.

ata3 is probably the DVD drive. If you physically remove the DVD drive do the issues stop? This doesn't solve getting your DVD drive running, but should make the rest of your computer run better.

Comment: Actually, my laptop is not slow but I will try with removing the dvd-rom.

Comment: do you know how can I disable it? I dont want to see them :(

Comment: Its best to remove the problem than mask it by disabling the messages. I had these errors for a while, also ata3 which was the DVD. The computer ran fine for about 6 months and I ignored it. After a while the PC got slow. I think the ata controller was messing up writing to the HDD because of it resetting when it got DVD errors. I had to sort out some corrupt files, but everything has been ok since. So probably best to get the drive out now just in case.